# angular2 : class FoodsComponent - caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular

In my component slick.slider.ts I do:

```
export class SlickSliderComponent  {

 $element: any;
 @ViewChild('el') el : ElementRef;
     // this.start = [{setting : "unslick"}];
     ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.$element = this.el.nativeElement;   
     }
}
```

And here I call the jquery slider:

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {

jQuery(this.$element).slick(this.options);
}
```

And in tne template when I call this component:

```
<slick-slider #el class="slick-tab-centered" *ngIf="foods" >
...
... 
</slick-slider>
```

I get this Error

```
class FoodsComponent - inline template:40:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get the native element of your component. so do this :

```
import { ElementRef } from "@angular/core";


export class SlickSliderComponent  {

     $element: any;
     constructor(private el :ElementRef){}
     ngAfterViewInit(){
         this.$element = this.el.nativeElement;   
     }
}
```

Comment: yes it solve the prb like that I already do it but the slide is not woring, and I want use ViewChild.